# Multimodal machine learning dataset fine tuning for binary classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, python

Hello i am new to machine learning, i am working on a multimodal dataset, basically memes dataset, The data consists of an image and an overlay text, i have no clue how to feed a model both of the information the text and image, for example what i understand for pytorch i can import and image dataset like pic number 1,2,3 and i can do some transformations to each image, but i am dealing with multimodal data, how can i feed in the text.[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! It might be a surprise to you that your question is off-topic here. This site focuses on the theory behind programming, not on programming using a particular language or software. Please see our [help on topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question might be on-topic on [SO] or [Data Dcience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ah, thanks John :D my bad.